# Finding regression equations from joint distribution

Tags: regression, self-study, conditional-expectation, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with joint probability density function $f(x, y) =  1$ if $− y < x < y, 0 <y< 1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Find the regression equation of $Y$ on $X$ and that of $X$ on $Y$.

So we're asked to find $E(Y|X)$ and $E(X|Y)$. I found the marginal density of $X$ to be $f_X(x)=1-|x|,-y<x<y$ and $f_Y(y)=2y, 0<y<1$. So then we have $f_{Y|X}(y)=\frac{1}{1-|x|}, f_{X|Y}(x)=\frac{1}{2y}$. Shouldn't they be function of $y$ & $x$ instead of $x$ & $y$ respectively? getting confused, how do I compute the conditional expectations?

Comment: In addition to Zhanxiong's answer, this is definitely one of those "draw the picture" problems. Can you visualize the joint density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not entirely wrong on conditional densities, but need to be more careful on domains. For example, the reason you felt that $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{1}{2y}$ is only a function of $y$ is because you did not write out the domain of $x$ explicitly (see my enhancement below). Also in the conditional density expression like this, $y$ should be viewed as a fixed number in its domain instead of an argument to a function.

The marginal density of $X$ should be
\begin{align}
f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
1 - |x| & |x| < 1, \\[1em]
0 & |x| \geq 1.  
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The marginal density of $Y$ found by you is correct.

The conditional density of $X$ given $Y = y$ ($0 < y < 1$) is:
\begin{align*}
f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{1}{2y}I_{(-1, 1)}(x). \tag{1}
\end{align*}

The conditional density of $Y$ given $X = x$ ($-1 < x < 1$) is:
\begin{align*}
f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f(x, y)}{f_X(x)} = \frac{1}{1 - |x|}I_{(0, 1)}(y). \tag{2}
\end{align*}

In terms of $(1)$ and $(2)$, conditional densities have their respective expected arguments $x$ and $y$.

Now it is easy to find regression functions based on $(1)$ and $(2)$:
\begin{align}
& E[X|Y = y] = \int_{-1}^1 xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx = 0, \quad 0 < y < 1; \\
& E[Y|X = x] = \int_0^1 yf_{Y|X}(y|x)dy = \frac{1}{2(1 - |x|)}, \quad -1 < x < 1.
\end{align}

Again, it is important to include domains such as "$0 < y < 1$" and "$-1 < x < 1$" above in your calculations, because by definition, regression functions are functions, and a complete specification of a function should include its domain.